# Remove center of rect with raphaeljs?

Tags: vector, svg, raphael

I am wondering if it is possible to say remove a circle from the center of a .rect object?

I cannot seem to find any questions or answers regarding the subject or any details so I am assuming no, but is there maybe another method of applying a dimmed background surrounding a center circle that could be scaled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=donutholes) of circle with a circle removed.

Then you can scale it or whatever.

Inside the path defition you can see a "moveto" (m) command in the middle so what you need to do is have the external shape as a rectangle.

Create your desired rectangle and circle inside that using an SVG editor such as Inkscape.

Remove the raw SVG of the 2 path (You should convert your svg:rect to svg:path inside the editor before saving)

Join the two paths with the moveto separating them. Experiment on the same screen. as shown above.